# при изменениях каждый раз опубликовывать web api net core.

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, asp

Я создал проект asp net core web api.

что я хочу:

Улучшить себе разработку локально web api.

Чтобы каждый раз когда я нажимал на `rebuild solution`, изменения подхватывались веб сайтом локально на iis.

Как происходит сейчас: изменения в коде > опубликовать web api > и папка `bin\Debug\PublishOutput` обновляется. (и в iss физический путь сайта `bin\Debug\PublishOutput` )

вопрос: как мне сделать, чтобы я не опубликовывал каждый раз проект при изменениях кода ?

когда я нажимаю `rebuild` я вижу что файлы в папке `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0` обновляются... 
но ведь там нет файла `web.config` мне его надо специально руками создать, да ? 
и в iss физический путь сайта, чтобы был `bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0` да ?

скриншоты:

[image: корневые файлы]

[image: папка PublishOutput]

Comment: скриншот: [файлы когда я нажимаю опубликовать](https://i.imgur.com/jZYhGOs.png)

Comment: Запускай CTRL+F5 (запуск без отладки)